# Query Optimization on Searching

Tags: mysql, sql, search, query-optimization, database-optimization

I am trying to create a search query for developing a school library that will retrieve data from the database with a low cost. Inside my table are **callNumber,author,title** and **year**. I want to search from callNumber, author and title.

```
$sqlCommand = "SELECT book_id, author, title 
               FROM book 
               WHERE MATCH(callNumber, author, title) 
               AGAINST('$search' IN BOOLEAN MODE)";
```

I used the query above and the return data is not reliable. Any suggestion or recommendation in optimizing this query, whatever. Thanks

Comment: Have you created appropriate indexes?

Comment: What do you mean "is not reliable"? You mean you're getting wrong results? The title implies that the problem is performance.

Comment: I get the right result but not in the first line of the results when i try to view it.

Answer (score 0):

Results of  `MATCH(...) AGAINST` queries are listed in order of relevance by default.

To list the relevance of the matches, try the following SQL:

```
SELECT book_id, author, title, MATCH(callNumber, author, title) 
               AGAINST('$search' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as relevance
               FROM book 
               WHERE MATCH(callNumber, author, title) 
               AGAINST('$search' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

If the relevance numbers are not what you expected you should consider whether your test data is relevant. There are some caveats, like:

- Short words are ignored (I think the cut-off is at 4 characters).
- Certain words are ignored (after, other etc).
- Common words are ignored (present in at least half the records)

I found [the following page](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=30875&seqNum=9) useful.